"E:The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."
Every time I try to install a new application or software(for eg: git,gcc to run c ,..), the above error is being thrown.
Here it is:
(base) devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo apt install gcc
[sudo] password for devi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

(base) devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

(base) devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

(base) devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-all hl1440lpr 
[sudo] password for devi: 
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove hl1440lpr which isn't installed (base) 
devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo rm -i /var/lib/dpkg/info/hl1440lpr.* rm: 
cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/info/hl1440lpr.*': No such file or directory (base) 
devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq hl1440lpr 
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove hl1440lpr which isn't installed 

My laptop's OS version is Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to open Software & Updates, it is not not opening, i.e. whenever I click on that app, it's coming back to my desktop page. Could this be the reason for the above error? If that is the reason, how to fix it?

Does this answer your question? E: The package needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Actually , I have tried the commands suggested in the similar questions ,but those are not worked.
(base) devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-all hl1440lpr
[sudo] password for devi:
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove hl1440lpr which isn't installed
(base) devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo rm -i /var/lib/dpkg/info/hl1440lpr.*
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/info/hl1440lpr.*': No such file or directory
(base) devi@devi-s200164:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq hl1440lpr
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove hl1440lpr which isn't installed

Don't use comments for updates on the question;  edit the question. Comments are for others to ask for something. code is "VS Code", did you remove the PPA for it?
